# Oracle Internal Error

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, errors, oracle-enterprise-manager

Getting oracle Internal error in oracle database 11gr2:

> ORA 600 [kkpogppi1]

It shows everyday in incidents but whenever i check oracle logs it shows nothing and when i open problem details it shows me:

[image]

So is this internal error and if yes then how could i solve this error and also is this any harmful to database?

Comment: You need to contact Oracle or check ["My Oracle Support"](https://support.oracle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The wording on this error might as well be:

> ORA-00600: "Something" is broken in the database.

It "recently" gained a close "cousin":

> ORA-07445: "Something" is broken, but not necessarily in the database itself.

If there's nothing immediately *obvious* in the logs, raise a Support call with Oracle.